# Need to put div between two div elements

Tags: html, css

I need to get this div

[What I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F0th.png)

My code:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to get this third div between two div elements but I don't know how. Need it for the school project. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: Please show us what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

The boxes you've labelled 1 and 2 need to be rectangles. Essentially, this means that Box #3 is visually placed in front of boxes 1 and 2. In order to achieve this, you can use `position: absolute` on `.div3` whilst also setting `position: relative` on your `.wrapper`. This is because children set to absolute positioning inside of a relatively positioned parent, are positioned in reference to the parent.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
  top: 50%;
}
```

Additionally, I recommend removing the white space within your curly brackets just to keep your code more simple.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple, the third div should overlap the two, for that it should be freely movable wrt to its parent to achieve this add a position: absolute, and add position relative to the parent

```
  .div3{
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    left:50px;
    }

.wrapper{
position : relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `position: absolute` on the third div and `position: relative` on its parent container.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="div2">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="div3">
    1
  </div>
</div>
```

```
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  height: 300px;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
}

.div1 {
  background-color: red;
  flex: 50%;
  width: 100px;
}

.div2 {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 50%;
  width: 100px;
}

.div3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [absolutely position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) the `<div>` element inside its container after making the container itself [relatively positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position). This allows you to place the element wherever you'd like inside the relative container.

To achieve the desired position, you can pull the element to the [bottom](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/bottom), push it to the [left](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left) by half the size of its container, then push it back by half its own size to center it using a [transformation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform).

Here's what the code looks like:

```css
.wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
  height: 180px;
  display: flex;
  /* relatively position the container */
  position: relative;
}
.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: red;
}
.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: green;
}
.div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  /* absolutely position the element */
  position: absolute;
  /* pull it to the bottom */
  bottom: 0px;
  /* push it from the left by half the size of the container */
  left: 50%;
  /* push it back by half its size to center it */
  transform: translate(-50%, 0%);
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div1">1</div>
  <div class="div2">2</div>
  <div class="div3">3</div>
</div>
```